# While loop in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in learning Python.
I am trying to understand the output of the following loop

```
iteration = 0
count = 0
while iteration < 5:
    for letter in "hello, world":
        count += 1
    print("Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count))
    iteration += 1
```

It firstly prints `Iteration 0; count is: 12`. I could get this.
But i miss something in the next step where `Iteration 1; count is: 24`. 
How come it is `24` and not `22`
Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: you forgot to reset the count on each iteration

Comment: Because 12 + 12 is 24. What do you expect to change between the first and second iteration?

Comment: At least this is because "... it is `24` and not `12`" (there is a typo in the question I presume ...

Comment: Why would it be 22? 12 + 12 is 24, the string `hello, world` is not changing each `while` loop iteration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - see my comment - guestimating :-)

Comment: If you thought it'd be 12, then you need to set `count` to zero **inside** the `while` loop (so it it set to 0 each iteration, not just once before the loops start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't reset the `count` variable after printing.
This occurs because you'd define the count variable **outside the scope** of your `while` loop, so it would only (I assume this isn't in a function) reset on rerunning your script.
By resetting the variable after printing it, or like [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) suggested, just using `count` only **inside the `while` loop scope**, it would also reset the value, as variables defined in a scope getting "discarded" after the interpreter leaves the scope.

So to get your expected result, you would change your code to something like this:

```
iteration = 0
while iteration < 5:
    count = 0 # this line needs to be added
    for letter in "hello, world":
        count += 1
    print("Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count))
    iteration += 1
```

Comment: Simpler: set `count = 0` **once**, as the first thing in the `while` loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my code.

Comment: Thank you. I dont need to modify the loop. I just try to get how it works.

Comment: @user6108949 Your question can be reduced to, "why doesn't count reset to 0 even though I don't explicitly reset it to 0 anywhere?"

Comment: @user6108949 I added some explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 12 "letters" in `"hello, world"`. The reason is that here `","` and `" "` Count as "letters" as well. So, if you only want to Count the real "letters" you have to exclude the Special chars in the process of counting.

In that case the Count for Iteration 0 would be 10, and for each Iteration will add another 10.

Comment: Why for each iteration it would add 10 if i exclude special characters, and if not it would add 12?

Comment: "hello, world" is a string of length 12. If you define a certain Group of "allowed" chars to Count within a string, and by that we talk about the Alphabetical Chars only, The Program will Count the letters of the string as if it was "helloworld", which is a String of length 10